# nginx - Proxy to a different backend based on query param

Tags: nginx

I've got a case where I want to proxy a particular call down to a different backend based on the existence of a query param. The following is sort of what I start with

```
location ~ ^/abc/xyz/?$ {
    proxy_pass $backend_url;
 }
```

What I'd like to do is check for a query param foo (or even just the existence of that string anywhere). So I thought I could do this

```
location ~ ^/abc/xyz/?$ {
    set $backend_url "somelocation"

    if ($request_url ~ .*foo.*) {
       set $backend_url "someotherlocation"
       proxy_pass $backend_url
    }
    proxy_pass $backend_url;
 }
```

But this doesn't seem to actually proxy to the new location. Am I doing something wrong with my code, or is the whole approach wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why are you using two `proxy_pass` directives, this block should do it in a logic you described:

```
location ~ ^/abc/xyz/?$ {
    set $backend_url "somelocation";
    if ($request_url ~ \?(.*&)?foo(=|&|$)) {
       set $backend_url "otherlocation";
    }
    proxy_pass $backend_url;
 }
```

I slightly modified your regex to match only request URLs where `foo` is a query argument name and not a query argument value (or its part). However I'd rather use `map` directive for this purpose (map block should be placed **outside** the server block):

```
map $arg_foo $backend_url {
    ""      somelocation;  # if the value is empty
    default otherlocation; # otherwise
}

server {
    ...
    location ~ ^/abc/xyz/?$ {
        proxy_pass $backend_url;
    }
}
```

Pay an attention you may need to define a [`resolver`](https://nginx.org/r/resolver) for this configuration to work (some additional info about this can be found [here](http://www.nginx-discovery.com/2011/05/day-51-proxypass-and-resolver.html)).

Comment: Thanks! I put th proxy_pass in there because in the real version of the code, there's a bit more stuff modifying the backend_url (some Lua module). But it might not be needed.

Comment: Re: your second suggestion - does arg_foo do something special (ie. Extract a query param named foo) or do I need to something to populate that?

Comment: Yes, you are right, `$arg_name` are special nginx variables to extract according query arguments ([here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) is the description). About your first comment - actually every `if` block is a virtual nested location that's trying to inherit all available directives from the previous level (sometimes including even those than are not normally inherited), so it isn't make a big difference.

Comment: `if` directive behaviour sometimes extremely unclear. An excellent explanation on how an `if` location works is made by Yichun Zhang, an author of `lua-nginx-module` and the OpenResty nginx fork: [How nginx "location if" works](http://agentzh.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html)